# How does jquery load() method affects the bandwidth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, server, bandwidth

I have two scripts on my server : script A and script B . On script A I want to load the script B every 1 second using this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function () {
    $('#myid').load('scriptB.html')
  }, 1000);
});
```

My question now is : if my script B has 10 kB does that mean that every 1 second 10 kB of bandwidth is consumed ?

Comment: As posted, no, because the browser will cache `'scriptB.html'`.

Comment: I would expect the browser to cache the contents of `scriptB.html` and not re-fetch it, or at most send only a `HEAD` (or `OPTIONS`?) request to check if it's been updated.  For your specific case you can always check your browser's debugging tools to observe *exactly* what's happening.

Comment: As mentioned in the above comments, no because of caching. But the larger question is why would you want to reload the same script over and over in the first place?

Comment: Also why load a `script` into some container? If you want to load a script there are other methods

Comment: My idea of it is because i don't want  my users to reload manually the script A in order to see the updates that are made on my database , so i found this option like an solution to automatically reload the script A

Comment: Is the content of `scriptB.html` dynamically created from your database? If so, that changes the question. To pick up the changes then the new content will have to be fetched, so yes each request will take an additional 10Kb of bandwidth. This is why AJAX polling is not a good idea. If you need to keep the client UI and server side data in close sync, use Websockets.

Comment: Thanks Rory its clear now